# Can we use HTML in Metadata fields?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, metadata, html

We have a series of procedural documents that are similarly named. I would like to create a document summary field as a piece of metadata that contains a paragraph about how the document is to be used, as well as provide alternates if someone has the wrong document by mistake.

For instance, when a user would search on "Billing", they may end up with 5 documents in a preview pane view. As they hover over the filename on the left and view the metadata on the right, there would be a field that may say something like:

```
This document is to be used when resolving customer billing issues. 
If the customer is a business customer, use *this-hyperlinked-document*.
If the customer is an institutional/government customer, use *this-other-hyperliked-document*.
```

However, when I enter the code to do that into a metadata field, I see this...visible tags.

```
This document is to be used when resolving customer billing issues. 
If the customer is a business customer, use <a href="this-document.doc">this-hyperlinked-document.</a>
If the customer is an institutional/government customer, use <a href="this-other-document.doc">this-other-hyperliked-document.</a>
```

It appears as if displaying metadata is supressing HTML and just reading the data as text. I'm wondering if this is a characteristic of metadata in general or if there's a way to make HTML tags work in the metadata field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behavior to protect for instance XSS and Javascript injections.

Comment: Any hack or workaround of which you're aware?